# How to safely output HTML from a PHP program?

Tags: php, html, escaping

When doing this job in PHP,one may meet this kind of issue:

```
<span title="<?php echo $variable;?>">...
```

The problem is that if `$variable` contains double quotes,should change it to `\"`

And that's not the whole story yet:

```
<span title='<?php echo $variable;?>'>...
```

In this case,we need to change single quotes to `\'`,but leave double quotes as is.

In addition, variable values may contain angle brackets < and > that will interfere with HTML.

So how can we safely escape output for HTML?

Answer (score 110, accepted):

You always want to HTML-encode things inside HTML attributes, which you can do with [`htmlspecialchars`](http://php.net/htmlspecialchars):

```
<span title="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($variable); ?>">
```

You probably want to set the second parameter (`$quote_style`) to `ENT_QUOTES`.

The only potential risk is that `$variable` may already be encoded, so you *may* want to set the last parameter (`$double_encode`) to `false`.

Comment: Confirmed with html5 specs here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5320177/what-values-can-i-put-in-an-html-attribute-value

Comment: +1 for mentioning "ENT_QUOTES". I was already using the this function but double quotes would mess up the html.

Comment: Note that ENT_QUOTES will still cause errors in javascript within html:

<a onclick="$.fancybox.open('<php echo htmlspecialchars($variable_with_single_quote, ENT_QUOTES); ?>')">link</a>

Use addslashes first and then htmlspecialchars to fix this issue.

Comment: @LeighBicknell I think it is better to do `htmlspecialchars(json_encode($variable), ENT_QUOTES)`. I haven't tested it in your particular example, but I think it should work nicely for any type of value.

Comment: Since PHP8.1 `ENT_QUOTES | ENT_SUBSTITUTE | ENT_HTML401` is the default value.

Answer (score 3):

Well, before you output any text into HTML you should escape it using [htmlspecialchars()](http://pl.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php). So just make sure (double) quote is correctly changed.

Pay attention to the second parameter of that function.

Answer (score -1):

The Bat tool has a StringTool::htmlAttributes ( $arrayOfAttributes ) method that does the job too.

https://github.com/lingtalfi/Bat/blob/master/StringTool.php