# Iterating inside a ng-if or ng-show in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am working on a AngularJS web application and sometimes I need to check if the element inside the ng-if or ng-show directive is inside a list. I'm doing this now:

```
<div ng-if="object.element=='A' || object.element=='B' || object.element=='C'">
    <p>Hello World!</p>
</div>
```

I was wondering if there is a way to do something like this:

```
<div ng-if="object.element in ['A','B','C']">
    <p>Hello World!</p>
</div>
```

Comment: use this way <div ng-if="object.element=='A'"> <div ng-if="object.element=='B'"> <div ng-if="object.element=='C'">

Comment: or see the example from here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20305012/angularjs-ng-if-with-multiple-conditions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do this:

```
<div ng-if="['A','B','C'].indexOf(object.element)>-1">
    <p>Hello World!</p>
</div>
```

Or this (it's the same):

```
<div ng-if="['A','B','C'].indexOf(object.element)+1">
    <p>Hello World!</p>
</div>
```

### [Working example](http://jsfiddle.net/mdg6e9u9/1/)

Answer (score 2):

Try this

**HTML**

```
<div ng-if="HideShow()">
    <p>Hello World!</p>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
    $scope.object = {
        element: 'A'
    };

   $scope.HideShow = function () {
        return $scope.object.element == 'A' || $scope.object.element == 'B' || $scope.object.element == 'C'
    }
```