# How to make equalization in ng-if? ( AngularJS )

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have ng-if problem. I want something similar to the php syntax in AngularJS. 
Example:

```
<?php 
$A = "Data";
if ( $A == "Data" ) {
$B = "ImData"; 
}
else{
$B = "ImNotData";
}
?>
```

How to make this syntax in AngularJS ng-if directive?

This does not work:

```
ng-if="A == 'Data' B='ImData'"
```

Comment: Which version did you use, I believe the latest syntax is `*ngIf`

Comment: My AngularJS Version : 1.6.4

Comment: Use a ternary operator

Comment: something like ng-if="A == 'Data' ? B='ImData' : $B = 'ImNotData'"

Comment: Thats working @Vega. Thank you very much. You are awesome, you are good person. If you want to answer me, i have one more question for this subject. How can i use AND, OR in this code? Example; `ng-if="A == 'Data' ? B='ImData' : $B = 'ImNotData'  && C== 'OtherData' ? D='ImOtherData' : D='ImNotOtherData'" ` Thats true?

Comment: Here is a good answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6260001/5468463

Comment: How about this https://stackoverflow.com/q/20305012/5468463?

Comment: @Vega Thank you so much for taking the time and helping me solve my problem. I hope you live a good life. God help you... Again thanks...

Answer (score 0):

suppose you have `isTrue` Boolean variable in controller

In controller:

```
$scope.isTrue = true;
```

In View:

```
<span ng-if="isTrue == "true">TRUE VALUE</span>
<span ng-if="isTrue != "true">OTHER VALUE</span>
```