# Jsoup does not escape special characters (<, >) inside quoted Element attribute values

Tags: java, jsoup

I got a surprise result when I tried to programmatically build an `Element` with attribute with value that contains `<` and `>.`

Am I missing something? https://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#syntax

The test:

```java
Element e = new Element("E");
e.attr("key", "value");
e.attr("code", "<X>");
assertEquals("<E key=\"value\" code=\"&lt;X&gt;\"></E>", e.outerHtml());
```

fails:

```
expected: <<E key="value" code="&lt;X&gt;"></E>> but was: <<E key="value" code="<X>"></E>>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What values can I put in an HTML attribute value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5320177/what-values-can-i-put-in-an-html-attribute-value)

Comment: This behavior is expected. See the duplicate question for more info.

Answer (score 0):

jsoup defaults to HTML output syntax, not XML. In HTML in a quoted attribute string, neither `<` nor `>` needs to be quoted, so jsoup doesn't.

If you want XML output, you can set [`OutputSettings`](https://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/nodes/Document.html#outputSettings(org.jsoup.nodes.Document.OutputSettings)) to `XML`.

As you're using `new Element()`, that element won't have a parent or a document until you insert it into the DOM.

So for example:

```java
Element e = new Element("E");
e.attr("key", "value");
e.attr("code", "<X>");
print("HTML", e.outerHtml());


Document doc = Document.createShell("https://example.com");
doc.outputSettings().syntax(Document.OutputSettings.Syntax.xml);
doc.body().appendChild(e);

print("XML", e.outerHtml());
```

Gives:

```html
HTML: <E key="value" code="<X>"></E>
XML:  <E key="value" code="&lt;X>"></E>
```

Note that in neither HTML nor XML does the `>` character in a quoted attribute need to be escaped, so jsoup doesn't do that.