# Escaping a string from database that goes on alt attribute

Tags: php, string, escaping

This should be fairly easy but I don't see what I'm missing here:

I have my database and I want the alt attribute to be populated from it.

I have my code as follows:

```
  <img src="admin/uploads/retouch/'.$list->thumbnail.'" class="thumb-image" alt="'.utf8_encode(addslashes($list->titulo)).'" />
```

And it happens that in this case what's inside "titulo" in my database has " on it and I get this as a result in my code:

```
  <img ti!\""="" por="" ¡hazlo="" manos.="" en="" estÁ="" prestaciones="" tus="" mejorar="" alt="\" class="thumb-image" src="admin/uploads/retouch/noticia_default.png">
```

the sentence from database is: "MEJORAR TUS PRESTACIONES ESTÁ EN TUS MANOS. ¡HAZLO POR TI!"

Comment: possible duplicate of [What's the best practice to set html attribute via PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2109583/whats-the-best-practice-to-set-html-attribute-via-php)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should be using `htmlspecialchars` not `addslashes`, with the utf8 option!

```
alt="'.htmlspecialchars($list->titulo, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8').'"
```

Comment: Have you set utf-8 on the page? `<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />`

Comment: Also try adding `utf8_encode` around the `$list->titulo` if it's not properly encoded.

Comment: Yeah, that utf8_encode did it, thank you very much, I learned something new today :D

Answer (score 1):

Use htmlentities or htmlspecialchars to escape strings in tag attributes.

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape such content using PHP function htmlspecialchars().

Answer (score 1):

You should encode htmlentities instead of adding slashes:

```
alt="'.htmlentities($list->titulo, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8').'"
```