# php - creating a dynamic canonical url

Tags: php, url, seo, canonical-link

Currently on my site I have duplicate URLs as follows:

```
example.com/post_title/
example.com/post_title_2/
example.com/post_title_33/
```

I have a canonical url set up in my site's header file that's used on every page as so:

```
<link rel="canonical" href="<?php echo $url ?>" />
```

where $url is the page url. So for example if the page URL is example.com/post_title_33/, the canonical is example.com/post_title_33/

My question is what would be the best way to make it so the canonical URL is always example.com/post_title/?

The numbers at the end of the URL can be any number not just 2 or 33 like I used in my example.

Comment: Note that your `echo` should be using the following to make it safe: `<?php echo htmlspecialchars($url); ?>`. If the URL includes characters that are not compatible with attribute data, it could break your whole page. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2109583/whats-the-best-practice-to-set-html-attribute-via-php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could remove the numbers and leading underscore with `preg_replace`:

```
<?

$input = array(
  'example.com/post_title/',
  'example.com/post_title_2/',
  'example.com/post_title_33/'
);

print_r(preg_replace('/_[0-9]+/', '', $input));

?>
```

Demo: https://eval.in/63138

Manual: https://www.php.net/preg_replace