# How to convert html code to php

Tags: javascript, php, html

I wish to convert button link with js from html to php

i added click function when i wrote this code in php the onclick function not working

Html

```
<button onclick="document.getElementById('id01').style.display='block'" style="width:auto;">

</button>
```

Corephp

```
<?php 
    echo '<button onclick="document.getElementById("id01").style.display="block" " style="width:auto;">';
?>

 This php echo line not working that means that onclick function.
```

Comment: `onclick="document.getElementById("id01").style ...` try counting the quote marks, you're going to need to escape some (or break out of PHP or use HEREDOC syntax) - I suspect if you view source you'll see the broken HTML in place.

Comment: Although it is useful to know the difference between client-side and server-side, I don't think it is the good duplicate to use for this question.

Comment: @Karl-AndréGagnon at risk of getting off topic can you suggest another? It is one I encounter frequently. oh wait, nvm, as in a 'bad close'. See my remarks. mea culpa.

Comment: @ficuscr This one may be better: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2109583/whats-the-best-practice-to-set-html-attribute-via-php. I've tested the solution with `onclick` instead of `title` and it works.

Comment: Or even the one you posted in your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Ah, I see. It is an escaping issue. Sorry, missed the mark with my first comment (Saw it as a client side / server side disconnect) and think I hijacked your question.

```
<?php 
    echo '<button onclick="document.getElementById(\"id01\").style.display=\"block\" " style="width:auto;">';
?>
```

These may help:

[Pass a PHP string to a JavaScript variable (and escape newlines)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/168214/pass-a-php-string-to-a-javascript-variable-and-escape-newlines)

[How to escape string from PHP for javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7085648/how-to-escape-string-from-php-for-javascript/7085956)

Comment: @Kalai, give a shout if you are still stuck.

Comment: i am not get. then i changed double quote to single like below echo '<button onclick="document.getElementById(\'id01\').style.display=\'block\' " style="width:auto;">'; this one is working. Thank you for your answer