# Quotes in a posted variable is not displaying with echo on the next page

Tags: php, post, echo

I have a hidden field
`<input type="hidden" name="thischeckout" id="thischeckout" value="<?php echo $htmlTable;?>">` in a form that is submitted.

When I use `<?php echo $_POST["thischeckout"];?>` on the next page, only a portion of the content is being displayed. I suspect quotes in $htmlTable are messing with the output.

Can I replace quotes with something that won't mess up when I output the POST via the php echo?

Comment: You probably need to escape the variable [`$htmlTable`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2109602/231316)

Comment: so escape, then remove the escape character to echo it?

Comment: Doesn't work. Still only getting partial value of the field.

Comment: Did you also set the `ENT_QUOTES` flag? Otherwise, your code might be producing something like `<input value="<table border="1"></table>">`. When a parser sees an opening quote for an attribute, it keeps reading until it finds a matching quote, so in my sample it finds `<input value="<table border="`. The value of an attribute is meaningless to the parser although it might look invalid to us. The parser then moves on and *might* find an attribute of `1`, or it might ignore, then another double quote and then the closing tag for the INPUT. I'm guessing that's what happening with yours.

Comment: Ah... that's EXACTLY what is happening. ```ENT_QUOTES``` solved it. Many thanks. 

BTW, how do I assign the answer to you?

Comment: I moved by comment down to an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you escape the output using [`htmlspecialchars`](https://www.php.net/htmlspecialchars), you have to tell the function the context for the escape. In this case, passing `ENT_QUOTES` is sufficient since that's really the only character that needs to be specially handled in a general HTML attribute.

```php
<input type="hidden" name="thischeckout" id="thischeckout" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($htmlTable, ENT_QUOTES);?>">
```