# Forms action field in html form - not redirecting to correct php code

Tags: php, html, action

Adding further explanation. I am pretty new to php but not programming in general.
I have a plugin for creating templates in wordpress and adding to the WP page editing screen
these templates are in a folder see below
C:\Wamp64\www\cbjaxon\wp-content\plugins\cgdmaintroutines\templates
these php file templates are file maintenance routines
there are sometimes a 00 and a 01 file that I need to move back and forth between
then there are 'non page' php files for inserting, deleting records as well as
things like db_connect.php, error handling, etc. these files are located in a folder
below the website folder cbjaxon i.e. cbjaxon/Code
when add, update etc button is clicked I need to call(?) these in the Code folder.
Also need to loop back from insert.php back to the 01 maintenance program.
I would have thought from what I've seen in Stackoverflow that if in a file in the
C:\Wamp64\www\cbjaxon\wp-content\plugins\cgdmaintroutines\templates
directory I could ust $url = 'filename' and put that in the action field in the form and
it would work. But it doesn't.
I know I'm rambling but I have been fighting this for days.

Using Wordpress to create pages.
File actually located in "c:/wamp64/www/cbjaxon/Code/schoolInsert.php"
Trying to set $url to appropriate url so can insert, delete and update. All the code files(insert, update, delete) located in same folder "c:/wamp64/www/cbjaxon/Code/?????.php.
Wordpress page code located in
C:\Wamp64\www\cbjaxon\wp-ontent\plugins\cgdmaintroutines\templates\schoolMaint01-tpl.php
So trying to set action field in form to the appropriate $url(and load into action field) to either insert, delete or update.
I have tried setting to $url to all kinds of things with ../'s, etc. as well as explicitly setting to actual file location as in the last one below.
The issue is that I do not know how to get the action field to navigate to my php code. I'm fairly new to php.
The version shown(is for add) and is the one I'm using as a test as it is the easiest to test.
The JS function validateFormOnSubmit is working as it does not produce an error.
As you can see from path below this is all being done at the moment on my local computer.

```
$url = "/cgdschoolInsert.php"; #
$url = "c:/wamp64/www/cbjaxon/Code/cgdschoolInsert.php";
?>
<div class="maintScreen">
    <form action="<?php echo $url ?>" name="schoolMaintForm"                          
                                  onsubmit="return(validateFormOnSubmit());" method="post">
```

Comment: You would want to take a loot at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2109602/10864272).

Comment: Remove the preceding `/` from `$url = "/cgdschoolInsert.php";` if the file is in the same folder where your current script is.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are trying to use the form to send a post request to `cgdschoolInsert.php`. A lot of information is missing from your question, but my assumptions are:

- Based on the destination PHP file, I am assuming that this PHP code is your INSERT action and you are having similar `cgdschoolDelete.php` for DELETE action and so on.
- The above code snippet with the form is published in some kind of web site on a web server (I am going to be using `http://example.com/mydoc.php` as a working example here).

**First things first:**
I am not sure about your templating and other setup, but the key is knowing the location of `cgdschoolInsert.php` on your website:

- `cgdschoolInsert.php` must be directly accessible from your browser on your web site
- Your `$url` must reflect the location of `cgdschoolInsert.php` on your web site, not in your server's file system.

In other words, you should be able to type the URL for `cgdschoolInsert.php` in your browser and access it. For example, if it is located in the same directory as `mydoc.php` (the document with your form), you should be able to access it from that form as `cgdschoolInsert.php` (no slash). If it is in the root of the web site, you can access it as `http://example.com/cgdschoolInsert.php`, or, alternatively as `/cgdschoolInsert.php`. If it is in a different directory, you will have to figure out the actual URL of it yourself. I am not familiar with your setup, so I cannot help there any further.

Please try that in your browser. If unsure, you can put a big `<?php echo '<h1>I am here</h1>' ?>` on the top of the `cgdschoolInsert.php` script to make sure your browser loads the right script.

**Then:**
Action URL may or may not contain domain. If, say, your mydoc.php script is served from `http://example.com/mydoc.php`, `$url = "/cgdschoolInsert.php"` would be having the same effect as `$url = "http://example.com/cgdschoolInsert.php"`. (The former would probably be better, saving you a lot of re-work if you decide to move your site to a different domain in the future.)

**Lastly:**
You want to implement different actions. You can do this in several ways. One suggested in your script is a different PHP script for INSERT, DELETE, UPDATE. In that case, you can use [PHP switch statement](https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php) to set the right $url "based on passed in variable" (as you mentioned):

```php
switch($passedVariable) {
    case "INSERT":
        $url = "/cgdschoolInsert.php";   // Change per your finding from the first point
        break;
    case "UPDATE":
        $url = "/cgdschoolUpdate.php";   // Change per your finding from the first point
        break;
    case "DELETE":
        $url = "/cgdschoolDelete.php";   // Change per your finding from the first point
        break;
    default:
        throw new Exception('Bad form action');
}
?>
<div class="maintScreen">
    <form action="<?php echo $url ?>" name="schoolMaintForm"  onsubmit="return(validateFormOnSubmit());" method="post">
    ...
```

**OR ALTERNATIVELY**

You can have one script for all actions, e.g. `cgdSchoolCRUD.php`. You can add a hidden form field into your form:

```html
<form ...>
    <input type="hidden" id="myAction" name="myAction" value="<?php echo $passedVariable ?>">
    ...
</form>
```

Inside the `cgdSchoolCRUD.php` you can use the switch statement to process the action:

```php
$myAction = $_POST["myAction"];

switch($myAction) {
    case "INSERT":
        // ... code to insert school
        break;
    case "UPDATE":
        // ... code to update school
        break;
    case "DELETE":
        // ... code to delete school
        break;
    default:
        throw new Exception('Bad form action');
}
```

Another small tip:
Depending whether it is enabled in your system, you may consider using [PHP short tags](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.phptags.php), which could make your HTML more readable. Instead of `<?php echo $url ?>` you can use the shorthand of `<?=$url ?>`.

Comment: Please see edited question. Maybe it is clearer. BTW: I really appreciate the time you took to respond. I'm trying different things now. Will let you know if I figure it out before hearing back.

Comment: Well I would have sworn I tried this one:  $url = "./Code/schoolInsert.php"; and it didn't work. But just tried and it did. Thanks so much for you efforts and guidance.

Comment: You are welcome! Please do not forget to upvote the answer :)